# Design an inventory class

Tags: c#, vb.net, oop, collections

I'm rewriting the infrastructure for an app and I've come through an interesting situation.

I'm writing a class `Bag`: the class has a property `Items` which can hold a collection of `Item`'s:

```
Weapon : Item
Armor : Item
Ammunition : Item
Bag : Item  (because a player may want to put a bag inside of another one)
```

Until here everything is fine, the problem is this...

In the front-end, while having different user controls for copies of a same `Armor` or `Weapon` is fine, that is not okay for `Ammunition` (like arrows) or `Item` (like breads).

A player can have, like, 50 arrows, and those need to be all represented as a single user control (a stack). The easy way to do that would be adding a `Quantity` property to the `Item` class and hide it from the `Armor`, `Weapon` and `Bag` classes, but that doesn't seem right, not only because I would have to hide it from the other derived classes, but also, in the end, any object in the world can exist in different quantities, so it doesn't seem right to make a class with a property like that.

It seems that the right way would be having a collection of `Item`'s for those items which can be stacked up (something like a `Stack(Of Item)`. So, in short: my `Bag` class must not only be able to hold a collection of items, but also a collection of collections of items.

For example, this is a screenshot of World of Warcraft:

[image]

As you can see, the backpack can hold both individual items and stacks of items.

How could I do that in a *nice* way?

Comment: You don't have to hide it at all, what you would need is a `Quantity` and a `MaxQuantity`, you either set the default `MaxQuantity` to be 1 and override it as necessary or set the items that can only have one to be 1. (I don't see how this question is too broad either)

Comment: I've thought about that already, but it doesn't seem to be a nice solution: Items and Ammunition have no Max Quantity, so a `MaxQuantity` property would be useless for them. Also, as I said, implementing a `Quantity` property in a class doesn't seem right as any object in the world can exist in different quantities. That's why we have collection classes.

Comment: @downvoter, please comment.

Comment: They should have a maximum imo, even if that is `int.MaxValue`, if you wanted to keep it realistic there shouldn't really be a way of designing a bag big enough to fit that much ammo, and then if you did the pure weight alone would make sure you wouldn't ever be able to use it

Comment: Why have a MaxQuantity property which simply represents int.MaxValue? That doesn't make much sense honestly. Also, the app is for tabletop RPG players (which can't play with pen and paper and need to play online). If you know tabletop RPG's, then you know that the last thing I should do is limit item's quantities to a "reasonable" level. What is "reasonable"? Only the Master/Narrator/Dungeon Master know that. Of course there will be a **technical** limit (which will be int.MaxValue), but, as I said, I don't think it makes much sense to store that in a `MaxQuantity` property.

Comment: I say max value simply because your program would dictate that limit anyway

Comment: @AndreSilva: Actually, I don't understand what you want to say by "any object in the world can exist in different quantities". That sounds like the perfect rationale to give those classes their `Quantity` property. You could add a class-specific flag that indicates whether a quantity is to be shown. Also, note that some games solve this in a simple way by always displaying a quantity if the quantity is >= 2, and otherwise only displaying the item picture.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't think so. As I said, I think that is exactly why we have collection classes. Does it make sense to you for a `Character` class to have a `Quantity` property as much as you think it does for an `Item`? No, right? And I know that some games do that, but it doesn't seem really nice. Note that I'm aiming for best code usability and maintainability. 
Although the accepted answer doesn't use collections, it manages to make it clear  for the developer why an item is represented, in the front-end, as a stack and not as an individual item.

Comment: @AndreSilva: Actually, yes, if I have 500 characters with exactly the same settings, it seems more reasonable to me to create a single character instance with those settings and a quantity property set to 500 than to create 500 individual character instances and store them in a list. As soon as there are larger numbers of a domain logic entity, representing clusters of objects rather than single objects starts being a viable design.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Really? That would be a terrible design. It might make sense from a performance perspective, but that is not my case. It simply and thoroughly makes sense for a `User` class to have a `List<Character> Characters` property. If `Character` had a Quantity property, the `User` class would then have a single `Character Character` property while the app would be still showing multiple characters for that user: simply a mess. 

I reiterate though: That might make sense from a performance perspective, but that is not my case. I'm aiming for code usability and maintainability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple solutions that I can think of

1. Make a Quantity and a MaxQuantity - Then items that are singular have a `MaxQuantity` of 1
2. Make a `StackableItem` class that ammo etc inherit from, you can then include a quantity into this and it would still allow you to carry multiple of the same item across different spaces if you wanted to. An example is shown in your screen shot of the red (armband?)

Comment: Well, creating a `StackableItem` class seems to be a nice [and simple] solution, I hadn't thought about that.

Comment: @AndreSilva - Seems reasonable to me also, you can always create methods in your item class to see if it is stackable (`return this is StackableItem`) which would help when adding to inventory